# floating action button aligned to bottom in API 21 and above?

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I have used floating action with that code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".menuscreens.AllRecipientsActivity">

    <GridView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/gridViewRecipients"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/action_button_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/action_button_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/action_button_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/action_button_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/action_button_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:tint="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/fabAddMoreRecipients"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Basically my problem is that in API 21 and above it is not getting margin from bottom**

and two screen shot which one is from bluestack API 19 and second is MotoG API 23

[API 19 bluestack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ro0f.png)

[API 23 MotoG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdnGH.png)

Comment: try android:layout_marginBottom and android:layout_marginLeft

Answer (score 1):

Use `app:useCompatPadding="true"` like below

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_add_place"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:useCompatPadding="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting this property

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
```